# FB debugger finds my og:image not big enough and force assigned one instead but all my files are big

Tags: debugging, facebook-graph-api, thumbnails

I am using joomla. when testing in FB debugger the page : http://tommigotphotography.com/en/galleries/wildlife

it finds all the images correctly but gives me a warning that my og:image provided is too small and it picks one of the images it founds for the thumbnail.

However, all my images are minimum 400px.

I used a joomla plugin called Content - Perfect Link with Article Images on Facebook PRO to force the generation of og properties dynamically and is meant to guarantee that all the images from my articles are being picked up by FB.

The plugin seems to be working fine according to the Graph API and the scraped URL output.

How can the debugger find all the images, all of them are bigger than the FB requirement and still throwing me:

```
Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 and     preferably 1500x1500. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image     'http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-    images_wildlife_wildlife-200902201651-tmp.jpg' will be used instead.
```

this is what the raw open graph shows:

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1316152835" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="wildlife" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url"  content="http://tommigotphotography.com/en/galleries/wildlife" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="TomMigotPhotography" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201303021431-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201303021355-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201208191617-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201208191511-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201207231745-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201205261600-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201201221557-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201112220317-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-201005061325-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-200902201651-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-200902201509-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-200902201157-tmp.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tommigotphotography.com/media/djmediatools/cache/700x400-toheight-images_wildlife_wildlife-200902181319-tmp.jpg" />
```

I have some announcement to make on FB and i cannot do it until FB enables me to select the appropriate image.

I hope i have been thorough with he details.

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Looks like you have other problems now: `The object at 'http://tommigotphotography.com/en/galleries/wildlife' previously had type 'article' and cannot be changed to an object of type 'website' to avoid data corruption of existing actions.`